# how can i make an octree 3d object?

Tags: java, processing

Why i can't divide a cube into several cubes until it becomes equal to 1 in this code ?

I first have a class box to draw the cube, second class octree I want to divide the cube into several sections I have tested whether the size of the box is equal to one or I will divide

```
class Quadtree {   
   Box boundry;  
   int capacity; 
 // max no. of points   
   ArrayList <Point> points ;  
   boolean divide = false;   
   Quadtree northeast;    
   Quadtree northwest;   
   Quadtree southeast;   
   Quadtree southwest;

   public Quadtree (Rectangle rect, int cap) {
      this.boundry = rect;
      this.capacity = cap;
      points = new ArrayList<Point>();   }

   public boolean insert (Point p) {
      if(this.boundry.radius == 1.0)
         return false;
      else{
         if(!this.divide){
            insert(p);
            this.subDivide();
     }
    return true;

    }   }   
   public void  subDivide () {
       PVector x = this.boundry.bottomRight;
       PVector y= this.boundry.bottomRight;
       float w = this.boundry.radius;
       float h = this.boundry.radius;

       this.northeast = new Quadtree(new Box (x.copy().add(new PVector(0, 0, 0)), w/2.0));
       this.northwest = new Quadtree(new Box (x.copy().add(new PVector(w/2, 0, 0)), w/2)); 
       this.southeast = new Quadtree(new Box (x.copy().add(new PVector(0, h/2, 0)), w/2));

       this.southwest = new Quadtree(new Box (x.copy().add(new PVector(w/2, h/2, 0)),w/2));
       this.divide = true;   }
```

I entered the infinite loop, although I have put a condition on whether it was Divided by or not ,Before that he would not divide the cube but draw cubes elsewhere .. In fact I did not know how to format the code or how I split the cube into a cube set in 3d space .. I did not find any source helping me in that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also fix the indentation of your source code to make it easier to read.

Comment: The edit is Done

Comment: You are still missing the MCVE. Please check [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your code](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging)? What is the value of `this.boundary.radius` right before you enter your `if` statement?

Comment: It's a width and  height of cube